# What does `Local` mean in my case?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I have an expression inside a function such as:

```
Class::Local.new(....)
```

What does `Local` mean? Does it mean that I'm trying to create a local object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Class::Local` is reference to a class `Local` from `Class` namespace.

`Class` can be a class or a module, but `Local` is a class, because you are creating an instance from it.

Comment: `Local` is a constant which references *some* object which responds to `new`. There is no way of knowing from that code snippet whether it's class or something else.

Comment: I figured out, this is the child class (Local) from basic (Class in my example)